# Mystery of the Abbey - How to track clues over time?

Tags: mystery-of-the-abbey

If I have Novice Gerard in my hand early in the game, and quickly learn that player A has one Templar Novice crossed off and player B has one Templor Novice crossed off, I know I can eliminate all three Templar Novices.

...However, if I learn early in the game that player A has one Templar Novice crossed off, and then learn *15 minutes later* that player B also has one crossed off, I need to somehow deduce whether they have the same Novice eliminated, or two different ones.  It would be helpful if I could look at my sheet and determine how old my previous clue was, and whether or not these players have had the chance to share this information with each other or not.  (Obviously, this is a simplified example, but hopefully you get the point.)

With a sheet covered in markings, it's easy to lose track of where and when I learned each piece of information, and this sometimes affects how I can interpret a new clue.  How do you go about tracking whether a clue on your sheet is "stale" or "fresh"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in games such as these is to make use of the directions my opponents face.  So, on the box for each monk, the player across from me will get the top-center of the box, while the player to my left gets the lower left of the box.  My notes will go in the appropriate location of the box for each player.  As for tracking the card movements, it's best to assume that knowledge is always shared, even if it wasn't, so the elimination note will pass from player A to player B anytime they exchange information.  This allows you to ask questions that you're SURE will leas to new information (if the question is answered as you hope), instead of possibly redundant information.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that it's not actually possible, and as a result my single playing was sufficient.

I was really disappointed because it's a beautiful game with a lot of neat ideas. If it was also a real deduction game I'd like it much more.